# Geometry Nodes: Get curve point count per spline

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Is there a way to store an attribute which contains the number of points for each spline of a curve?

In the following exemple I have a curve object with multiple spline in it.
They have respectively 2, 3, 5 and 12 points. When I use the Domain Size node I get 22 which is the sum of points in each spline, not what I want.

[image]

Comment: please show us your whole node tree or even better - provide blend file - so you will attract more people who are willing to answer and are a bit lazy (like me). thx.

Comment: you could also find it out with sample curve like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCSOW.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[Points of Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve_topology/points_of_curve.html)" is the node you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @lemon :) Its working welll

Answer (score 3):

For exactly this use case the node `Spline Length` is available.

Contrary to its name, this node gives you not only the length of each spline, but also the number of its points.

[image]

The advantage is that this node is already included from version 3.0.

Comment: Thanks @quellenform It is also working for me :)